# What exactly happens in gradient clipping by norm?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gradient-clipping

Consider the [following description](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_.html) regarding gradient clipping in PyTorch

```
torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(parameters, max_norm, norm_type=2.0, error_if_nonfinite=False)
```

> **Clips** gradient norm of an iterable of parameters.
>
> The norm is computed over all gradients together as if they were
> concatenated into a single vector. Gradients are modified in-place.

Let the weights and gradients, for loss function $L$, of the model, be given as below

\begin{align}
w 
&= [w_1, w_2, w_3, \cdots, w_n] \\
\triangledown 
&= [\triangledown_1, \triangledown_2, \triangledown_3, \cdots, \triangledown_n] \text{, where } \triangledown_i = \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial w_i} \text{ and } 1 \le i \le n
\end{align}

From the description, we need to compute gradient norm, i.e. $||\triangledown||$.

How to proceed after the step of finding the gradient norm? What is meant by clipping the gradient norm mathematically?

Answer (score 4):

Gradient clipping is a technique that tackles exploding gradients. The idea of gradient clipping is very simple: If the gradient gets too large, we rescale it to keep it small. More precisely,

$$
\text{if } \Vert \mathbf{g} \Vert \geq c, \text{then }
\mathbf{g} \leftarrow c \frac{\mathbf{g}}{\Vert \mathbf{g} \Vert}
$$

where $c$ is a hyperparameter, $\mathbf{g}$ is the gradient, and $\Vert \mathbf{g} \Vert$ is the norm of $\mathbf{g}$.

Since $\frac{\mathbf{g}}{\Vert \mathbf{g} \Vert}$ is a unit vector, after rescaling the new $\mathbf{g}$ will have norm $c$.

Note that if $\frac{\mathbf{g}}{\Vert \mathbf{g} \Vert} < c$ , then we don’t need to do anything.

Check [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/what-is-gradient-clipping-b8e815cdfb48)  for more information

Comment: This appears to be copy-pasted from [another source](https://towardsdatascience.com/what-is-gradient-clipping-b8e815cdfb48), without appropriate attribution.  We have certain rules that we require you to follow whenever copying from another source: https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.  Please [edit] your answer to follow them.